# Opencart 3.0.2.0 Auto logout issue

Tags: session, opencart-3

So I am experiencing this frustrating issue for quite some time already. The scenario is when I am using admin panel, it will automatically log me out frequently(especially when I click on Save or Edit button). Sometimes it was as bad as each action click it will log me out once, so I have to repeatedly login for each action I performed( Save or Edit).

It is even worst that this is not a constant issue which means it is not every time I click on this module will have this issue which makes me impossible to trace under what circumstances this issue will comes out. By the way, after the system log me out, the message appeared at the login page was 'Invalid session token'.

And recently I got feedback from my customer that even front end is having this issue. My customer make an order after filling up all the details and confirm the payment, when try to click next button, he is being logout !! No order confirmation email send to him. And when he re-login to his account, his order details is incorrect(showing other customer details). This has seriously impact my website reputation. I believe both these front end and backend issue were from the same root cause.

All this while I have been trying to look for solution for this, I have seen similar post on Opencart forum before but can't get a solid solution. So I am opening this topic again here and hope to get a solution from stackoverflow. Solid solutions/advise/idea are all welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may check at following things,

1. delete system/logs/error.txt;
2. check if problem has gone;
3. if not - check where is your disk_space (you may contact your hoster for support)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue.

I have changed the string of code in the htaccess file from "http" to "https" and that worked for me.